# Не работает простой socket server. Дочерний поток блокирует основной

Tags: python, многопоточность, сокет

Проблема с простым примером socket server с обработкой каждого входящего соединения в отдельном потоке (thread). Такое впечатление что созданный для обработки нового соединения поток блокирует выполнение основного потока. Есть код сервера:

```
import socket
import threading

def worker(conn, addr):
    with conn:
        while True:

            print("wait recv from", addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            print("recv", data)

            if not data:
                break


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(("", 7001))
    sock.listen(socket.SOMAXCONN)
    while True:

        print("wait accept...")
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        print("accept new connection from", addr)

        th = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(conn, addr))
        th.start()
        th.join()
```

Запускаю два socket клиента. В двух консолях набираю код в интерпретаторе python:

```
import socket
s = socket.create_connection(("", 7001))
s.send(b"ping")
```

Соединение остаётся висеть открытым. При этом в консоли сервера вижу сообщения только об одном соединении. А вот когда закрываю его выполнив код

```
s.close()
```

Тогда уже появляются сообщения о втором клиенте. Такое впечатление что строчка data = conn.recv(1024) блокирует не только свой поток, но и основной, в котором должно ожидаться новое соединение.

Собственно вопрос: тут ошибка в коде или это нормальное правильное поведение?

Comment: `th.join()` уберите.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло. Так понял что именно эта строка блокировала выполнение основного потока до завершения дочернего (что она и должна делать по описанию). Благодарю за помощь.